# How to set display to a higher resolution?

Tags: xorg, freebsd, nvidia

I'm runnning FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE and I'm getting a low resolution 640x480 in the xfce session,I don't have the option to get to a higher one in settings.

Here is my xorg.conf file [xorg.conf](http://pastebin.com/cd7Q6xUb)

Comment: Please show us also  `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, so that we can see any errors.

Comment: Hardware details?

Comment: Did you try with nvidia-settings ?